# Break Stack Exchange

Tags: popularity-contest, underhanded, browser

Trick the user that StackExchange is broken:

[image: Stack Overflow error page]

It can be done in several ways:

- Your program starts a browser in some certain way (with a proxy server, for example);
- Your program shows static picture;
- Your program is executed in address bar using `javascript:`.
- (your other creative way)

StackExchange error page should be displayed to user one way or another. It may appear immediately or after user tries to do something (i.e. to post a comment). The program should look like some useful StackExchange enhancer (e.g. a userscript that highlights happy posts, i.e. posts containing the word `happy`).

Try to aim for the shortest program (original tag was [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)) and/or obfuscated code. You may depend on some concrete browser (Firefox, Chromium, Opera).

Encouraged:

- Preserving address line "normal";
- Finding actual faults in StackExchange software;
- Making it "hard to fix" (on this computer), e.g. making it cached;
- Making it show different error depending on on which site do I start the program (if it is a in-browser snippet);

Discouraged:

- Simply redirecting to [`http://.../error`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/error). You can still try to sneak it [underhanded](/questions/tagged/underhanded)-style.
- Trying to permanently mess with user's StackExchange account.

(inspired by [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/3350/935))

Comment: This seems to be too vague for me. "As closely as possible" is not really an objective criterium.

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12340/make-stackoverflow-explode-bookmarklet

Comment: @Quincunx No, that is very different - it allows much more than displaying errors.

Comment: @IngoBürk Yeah, I would suggest removing that line and just saying "Must display an image of the error page"

Comment: @isaacg But then it comes down to golfing a picture. We've had that before. Quite recently, even, I think.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because underhanded challenges are no longer on-topic on this site. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8326/20469

Comment: @cat, Is PPCG definition shifting (or shifted) compared to two year ago? I though the sole reason of PPCG is to offload funny code trickery with away from StackOverflow. Underhanded contests or code trolling definitely feel like a funny trickery...

Comment: @Vi. Yes. undefined and undefined are now discouraged, as they don't provide an objective primary winning criterion. Did you read the meta post I linked?